# How do you get server blocks <% %> to format well in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm using ASP.NET MVC a lot recently which means using server blocks a bunch.  Visual Studio does this strange thing when I type:

```
<% } %>
```

and hit enter, I get this:

```
<%
     }
     %>
```

Which is unsightly and generally the most horrible thing I've ever seen.  I've customized the Ctrl+K+D behavior pretty heavily and when I do this I get everything to look the way I want except for this one case.  Anyone have any suggestions on how to customize this?

Comment: OMG I want to know to! thanks for asking!

Comment: Good question, this has been bugging me since I started using MVC regularly.

Comment: Y'all should submit this to the MS Connect feedback site and vote it up like crazy and they might fix it.

Comment: You should subnmit it to http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ then post the bug/suggestion URL here, then whoever cares should vote _once each_. Screw with voting and they'll just ignore the entire suggestion.

Comment: If someone does post it to MS Connect, link back here so we can upvote it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the behavior. I don't know that you can override it just for the HTML editor. It is exhibiting the exact behavior that is defined in the C# editor preferences.

I suppose you could modify the behavior for a closing brace in the C# editor preferences, but it would do fugly things to your .cs files.

Edit:

I got tired of trying to find other ways to do it. So I wrote this macro. Tested in VS 2k8. Not 2k5. You can see what it does. Also, sorry about the VB, but it was the default for the macro editor.

```
Sub FixFormatCurrentFile()

    Dim selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    Dim fixed As String = "<% } %>"
    Dim regex As String = "\<\%:Wh*\}:Wh*\%\>"

    While selection.FindPattern(regex, vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsRegularExpression)
        selection.ReplacePattern(regex, fixed, vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsRegularExpression)
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with using macros in Visual studio...can I essentially attach this to Ctrl+K+D?

Comment: Not to ctrl-k-d, its going to have be an extra keystroke, I believe. You could however, likely call the 'autoformat' within the macro first.

Answer (score 0):

i think you format it by Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D