# ASP.NET MVC View Code Formatting - braces <% } %>

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, code-formatting

Does anyone know how to configure visual studio to correctly format code segments within a View

This annoys the crap outta me!:

```
<select>
<%
foreach(Height height in ViewData.Model.Heights)
{%>
<option value="<%=height.ID %>"><%=height.Value%></option>
<%
}%>
</select>
```

It should be like this:

```
<% foreach(Height height in ViewData.Model.Heights) { %>
    <option value="<%=height.ID %>"><%=height.Value%></option>
<% } %>
</select>
```

I can fix it manually but whenever I reformat, or change some of the code close to the braces it screws up again!

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720042/how-do-you-get-server-blocks-to-format-well-in-visual-studio

Comment: Bugs me too... looking forward to an answer.

Comment: Removed MVC tag, this happens using webforms as well.

Answer (score 1):

After the auto formatting takes place hit cntrl-z, it will undo the auto-formatting only and not rearrange your code.